# Can someone perform DDoS on my VPS even if it is only accessible through SSH?

Tags: webserver, server, ddos, web, vps

Can someone perform DDoS on my VPS even if I have not installed any webserver software like apache, nginx, etc.? Since I have not installed any webserver software, it's not really available to the public. Am I right? It can only be accessed via SSH.

Answer (score 5):

DDOS means Distributed **Denial of Service**. If no service is provided by your VPS then no service can be denied. If SSH is provided then SSH can be denied. This means a DDOS can actually work against your system too: if all the bandwidth is taken by the attack or your system is busy trying to process connection attempts to SSH then you will not be able to login anymore yourself, i.e. the service is denied for you.

Additionally your VPS shares the hardware with other VPS which all share the same bandwidth and CPU. Due to this if any of the other VPS gets attacked it might affect your VPS too.

Comment: I see. If only SSH is working even then an attacker can perform DDOS attack to make VPS consume its entire bandwidth and even I won't be able to login via SSH. Is there any way to access VPS without using SSH (and also without FTP) ?

Comment: @Yujx: This depends on your VPS provider. They often offer some kind of remote desktop or similar interface. But note that this can be attacked too. And the "V" in VPS also means that you share the hardware and thus also the available bandwidth with other VPS so you might be affected if these get attacked (depending on the kind of attack).